# How do I make a multidimentional array display all of it's values in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

Mainly self-explanatory from the title, trying to display this array in console.

```
    Sub Array()
    Dim board(5, 5) As String
    board(1, 1) = "-"
    board(1, 2) = "|"
    board(1, 3) = "-"
    board(1, 4) = "|"
    board(1, 5) = "-"
    board(2, 1) = "-"
    board(2, 2) = "|"
    board(2, 3) = "-"
    board(2, 4) = "|"
    board(2, 5) = "-"
    board(3, 1) = "-"
    board(3, 2) = "|"
    board(3, 3) = "-"
    board(3, 4) = "|"
    board(3, 5) = "-"`
```

Comment: The answer is self-explanatory: use a loop

Comment: Im seriously new to coding, so I didn't really find it self-explanatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a loop, as suggested by others, is the answer.  However, with a multidimensional array it's not quite as simple as that sounds.  If you want to print the array as a grid you will need nested loops and to know that you can get the bounds of each array dimension using [`Array.GetLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength(v=vs.110).aspx).  So, something like this might give you what you are looking for:

```
For i = 0 To board.GetLength(0) - 1
    For j = 0 To board.GetLength(1) - 1
        Console.Write(If(board(i, j), ""))
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Result (with some blank lines removed - see later):

```
-|-|-
-|-|-
-|-|-
```

You will notice that I used `If(board(i, j), "")` when printing the values - that's because your array is littered with null values and when I tested in LINQPad it was printing out "null" for those values.  A regular console may not be as picky, or may be more picky and start beeping at you (I didn't test it out).

The reason for some of the nulls is that when you define an array you are specifying the upper bounds for each dimension, and the bounds are zero based, so `Dim board(5, 5) As String` gives you an array with 6 elements in each dimension (0 through 5).  You are skipping the 0 indexes, so currently your array looks like this:

[image: Array Layout]

I suppose you could adjust your loops to compensate (e.g. start at 1 instead of 0), but that's not something I would recommend.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate means alot, sorry if my question seemed vague or  stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `For Each`:

```
For Each item In board
   Console.WriteLine(item)
   'Or as one-liner:
   Console.Write(item)
Next
```